# Firebase Cloud Function: An issue with Auth callbacks

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have two Auth callbacks, when a user was created and deleted. Each callback fired successfully, but produces the same error: `TypeError: handler is not a function at cloudFunction`. It seems I was wrong with callbacks' syntax, but I can't find right example for V1 functions. Please help, thanks.

Also: how can I deploy these funcs to europe-west1 insted of us-central1, is it possible for V1 functions?

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions"); // v1
const {initializeApp} = require("firebase-admin/app");
initializeApp();

const db = getFirestore();

exports.authUserCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate({region: "europe-west1"}, (user) => {
  const userEmail = user.email;
  const userId = user.uid;
  return db.collection("users").doc(userId).update({createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp(), email: userEmail});
});

exports.authUserDeleted = functions.auth.user().onDelete({region: "europe-west1"}, (user) => {
  const userId = user.uid;
  return db.collection("users").doc(userId).delete();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass an object as the first argument to `onCreate()`. That's v2 syntax, but you are writing a v1 function.  Follow the example in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation):

```
exports.sendWelcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // ...
});
```

There is only one argument - the handler function.

If you want to set the region on a v1 type function, there is [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/locations#best_practices_for_changing_region) for that as well:

```
exports.myStorageFunction = functions
    .region('europe-west1')
    .storage
    .object()
    .onFinalize((object) => {
      // ...
    });
```

So you will need to do something like this:

```
exports.authUserCreated = functions
  .region("europe-west1")
  .auth
  .user()
  .onCreate(user => { ... })
```

You might also want to review the [API documentation for the firebase-functions module](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions).